# Quasar Framework Vue Js -privilege for login

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework, supabase-database

I am new to using the quasar Vue Js framework and as a database I use supabase.
It currently works without any problems, I need to be able to grant the privilege or limit so that only a specific user can access the login since currently all users can access the login, I don't know where in my code I can add the filter to that only a specific user can enter with their email and password.

```
<template>
  <img src="~assets/wave.png" class="wave" alt="login-wave"  style="height: 150vh">
  <div class="row" style="height: 90vh">
    <div class="col-0 col-md-6 flex justify-center content-center">
      <img src="~assets/login.svg" class="responsive" alt="login-image">
    </div>

    <div v-bind:class="{'justify-center': $q.screen.md || $q.screen.sm ||$q.screen.xs}"
         class="col-12 col-md-6 flex content-center" >
      <q-card v-bind:style="$q.screen.lt.sm ? {'width': '80%'} : {'width': '50%'}">
        <q-card-section>
          <q-avatar size="103px" class="absolute-center shadow-10">
            <img src="~assets/indexum_circle.png" alt="avatar">
          </q-avatar>
        </q-card-section>
        <q-card-section>
          <div class="q-pt-lg">
            <div class="col text-h6 ellipsis flex justify-center">
              <h2 class="text-h4 text-uppercase q-my-none text-weight-regular">ACCESO</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </q-card-section>
        <q-card-section>
          <q-form class="row justify-center" @submit.prevent="handleLogin">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 q-gutter-y-md">

        <q-input label="Email" v-model="form.email" lazy-rules
          :rules="[val => (val && val.length > 0) || 'Email is required']" type="email"   />

        <q-input label="Clave" v-model="form.password" lazy-rules
          :rules="[val => (val && val.length > 0) || 'Password is required']"/>

        <div class="full-width q-pt-md">
          <q-btn label="Login" color="primary" class="full-width"  rounded type="submit" />
        </div>

      </div>
          </q-form>
        </q-card-section>
      </q-card>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent, ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
import useAuthUser from 'src/composables/UseAuthUser'
import useNotify from 'src/composables/UseNotify'
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'PageLogin',

  setup () {
    const router = useRouter()

    const { login, isLoggedIn } = useAuthUser()
    const { notifyError, notifySuccess } = useNotify()

    const form = ref({
      email: '',
      password: ''
    })

    const handleLogin = async () => {
      try {
        await login(form.value)
        notifySuccess('Login successfully!')
        router.push({ name: 'me' })
      } catch (error) {
        notifyError(error.message)
      }
    }

    onMounted(() => {
      if (isLoggedIn) {
        router.push({ name: 'me' })
      }
    })

    return {
      form,
      handleLogin
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

Class UseAuthUser - supabase

```
import { ref } from 'vue'
import useSupabase from 'boot/supabase'

const user = ref(null)
export default function useAuthUser () {
  const { supabase } = useSupabase()
  /**
   * Login with email and password
   */
  const login = async ({ email, password }) => {
    const { user, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithPassword({ email, password })
    if (error) throw error
    return user
  }


  /**
   * Logout
   */
  const logout = async () => {
    const { error } = await supabase.auth.signOut()
    if (error) throw error
  }

  const { listPublic } = useApi() */
  const isLoggedIn = () => {
    return !!user.value
  }

  return {
    user
  }
}
```

class routes

```
const routes =
  [
    {
      path: '/',
      component: () => import('layouts/LoginLayout.vue'),
      children: [
        { path: '', name: 'loginDefault', component: () => import('pages/Login.vue') },
        { path: 'login', name: 'login', component: () => import('pages/Login.vue') },
        { path: 'register', name: 'register', component: () => import('pages/Register.vue') },
        { path: 'email-confirmation', name: 'email-confirmation', component: () => import('pages/EmailConfirmation.vue') },
        { path: 'forgot-password', name: 'forgot-password', component: () => import('pages/ForgotPassword.vue') },
        { path: 'reset-password', name: 'reset-password', component: () => import('pages/ResetPassword.vue') }

      ]
    },
    {
      path: '',
      component: () => import('layouts/MainLayout.vue'),
      children: [
        { path: 'me', name: 'me', component: () => import('pages/Me.vue') },
        { path: 'attendance', name: 'attendance', component: () => import('pages/attendance/List.vue') }
        // { path: '', component: () => import('pages/IndexPage.vue') }
      ],
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      }
    },

    // Always leave this as last one,
    // but you can also remove it
    {
      path: '/:catchAll(.*)*',
      component: () => import('pages/ErrorNotFound.vue')
    }
  ]
export default routes
```

I need to achieve the following since I am developing the backend of a website and I am working with the same database where I have all the users registered in the supabase authentication table and I need only one user to be able to manage the backend. thanks greetings